# Light on/off in Frigidaire Chest Freezer

Tags: freezer

I have a Frigidaire Chest Freezer (FFCL1542AW) and am trying to work out how to disable the light that goes on when the lid to the freezer is opened.  I assume its triggered by a magnetic senor that activates the light when the lid is open, but i have run a magnet along the top lip with no luck.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Unscrew the bulb. Or is it an integrated LED?

Comment: probably uses a tilt switch

Comment: Why? to save energy? Opening the lid wastes more energy by allowing warm air into the freezer...

Comment: This is an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). What is it you're trying to solve by disabling the light? Are you worried that your neighbors will see into your freezer, realize that it's stocked with delectable venison, and come steal it at night?

Comment: Many units have the electrical schematic inside the back cover, a clear photo of that will usually allow us to identify how to fix or in this case disable the light.

Comment: You can cover it with black duct tape or similar.

Comment: Just unplug it. The light will stop. ;)